# Proof of composite

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, x^2 + 5x + 4$ is composite.

Comment: Note that your answer needs to exclude the possibility that one of the factors may be $1$ - or to deal with this case separately (e.g. $1\times 4=4$ is composite because $4=2\times 2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorise $x^2 + 5x + 4$ into $(x+1)(x+4)$. For $x$ even note that one factor is odd and other even. For $x$ odd one factor is even and other odd. Thus always is even and composite.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial can be rewritten as $$(x+1)(x+4)$$ which is in $\mathbb{N}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Now observe, that both factors are larger than $1$ for any natural number $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $$x^2 + 5x + 4$$ has other divisors than $1$ and itself, hence it is composite. This is taken from the second line [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$x^2 + 5x + 4 = (x+1)(x+4).$$

Comment: I know but how do we proceed from there? Essentially proving it to be true using the definition of a composite number.

Comment: $x^2 + 5x + 4 = (x+1)(x+4).$ is composite since it has factors $(x+4)$ and $(x+1)$, and $x+4>4$ with a natural numbered value.

Comment: @HKT: What IS your definition of "composite" if $(x+1)(x+4)$ does not _immediately_ fit it?